# loosening tan-colored thread-lock compound on black-iron pipe

Tags: pipe, boiler

I need to replace the 4 gallon Amtrol expansion tank on my hydronic heating system. The tank is threaded into a black-iron 90-degree fitting; whoever installed it originally used a tan-colored thread-lock compound. I cannot get the tank to budge with a pair of 12-inch channel lock pliers. I've tried a hefty adjustable wrench and tapping the wrench with a hammer. No joy.

Do some of these thread-lock compounds respond to a bit of heat?

Answer (score 1):

That's probably old gas/water thread compound, and not a thread locker. It could also be plumber's putty, which does tend to get quite hard.

Solvent probably won't do you any good, and you've presumably had some heat in it already. You could try heating it locally with a torch. What remains after that is ever-larger wrenches.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try to tighten the pipe thread just a little bit. The strain on the threads are in the direction of tightening and will be easier to turn. If you can turn the threads just a slight amount this will break the pipe dope seal and will make it easier to turn the fittings the other way to remove the tank.